# Angular - Injecting components dynamically to another component's template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I'm working on an Angular component. This component would be the header of the website, it would appear on every page with different content (but not only strings and this is the problem).

I can pass a string or even raw HTML dynamically, but the components are not rendering, they're stripped out.

In AngularJS 1, I could use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) but in Angular, that's not available and I don't know how to solve this.

This supposed to be a very very easy step, I could solve this problem with raw Javascript within 5 minutes and 10 lines of code, this is an easy DOM change, but in Angular, this seems to be impossible and I don't know why is that hard.

## Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContentHeaderService {

  private titleSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
  private infoSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
  private hintSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
  private backgroundSource = new BehaviorSubject(environment.contentHeaderDefaultBg);
  title = this.titleSource.asObservable();
  info = this.infoSource.asObservable();
  hint = this.hintSource.asObservable();
  background = this.backgroundSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeTitle(str: string) {
    this.titleSource.next(str)
  }

  changeInfo(str: string) {
    this.titleSource.next(str)
  }

  changeHint(str: string) {
    this.titleSource.next(str)
  }

  changeBackground(str: string) {
    this.backgroundSource.next(str)
  }
}
```

## Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ContentHeaderService} from "../../services/content-header.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content-header',
  templateUrl: './content-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content-header.component.scss']
})
export class ContentHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  background: string;
  title: string;
  info: string;
  hint: string;

  constructor(private data: ContentHeaderService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.background.subscribe(background => this.background = background)
    this.data.title.subscribe(title => this.title = title)
    this.data.info.subscribe(info => this.info = info)
    this.data.hint.subscribe(hint => this.hint = hint)
  }

}
```

## Template

```
<div class="content-header position-relative bg-light-blue text-center text-sm-left pattern-bg" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + background + ')'}">
  <div class="py-5 " style="">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="mb-0" [innerHTML]="title"></h1>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <span class="text-light" [hidden]="!info"><span><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> {{info}}</span></span>
        <span class="text-light" [hidden]="!info"><span><i class="fas fas fa-lightbulb"></i> {{hint}}</span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## The Problem

I want to place 100% dynamic content for the inputs (especially for the `title`), for example:

`My Progress, <mdb-progress value="0" min="0" max="50" aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="50"></mdb-progress>`

another page:

`My Profile <mdb-badge color="red">Edit</mdb-badge>`

So I want to define a header component in one place but also want any unknown number of other components to be able to inject to the header if I want.

I've found a couple of half-workarounds to solve this, but nothing was totally dynamic. Since I have hundreds of reusable components (attribute directives) in my project I can't put all of them into the header component's template with a condition for each. That would be extremely heavy and hard to update.

So I'm looking for a 100% dynamic solution. A 100% flexible header.